# How do I upgrade Microsoft R Open when its installed from the Microsoft Machine Learning Server on Ubuntu?

Tags: r, ubuntu-16.04, microsoft-r

How do I upgrade Microsoft R Open on Linux?

The latest Microsoft Machine Learning Server `9.3.0`, (Formally [Microsoft R Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/rebranding-microsoft-r-server)) automatically installs MRO however it hasn't been kept as up-to-date as MRO has. Currently it installs `Microsoft R Open 3.4.3`.

MMLS is installed to: `/opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.3.0`

R is installed to: `/opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.3.0/runtime/R`

### Could I just delete the `R` folder above and replace it with the latest R version?

> $ whereis R
>
> R: /usr/bin/R /usr/local/lib/R

Comment: You'll probably need to contact Microsoft to ask this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The current version of MRO (MRO 3.5.1) is not compatible with Machine Learning Server 9.3.0--the R internals have changed, and so the various MLS R packages built under 3.4.3 will not work with R 3.5.1.

Regards,
Rich Calaway
Microsoft R Open Team